# how the data inserted are stored in database while creating in yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

i did not understand how the data stored in database while inserting. please clear the storing of data in db in YII framework

Comment: Please provide some code. Gives a better understander of the ones that might have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yii is an MVC freamework, which means, that the data handling has to be defined by the developer in the model part. Here you define, what attributes are available and how the are stored in an database.

Take a look at this: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models